# Kids' story about a Christmas tree that was sad because no one would buy it

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

There was a Christmas tree for sale but no one bought it because it had a twisted trunk. It was very sad because no one would buy it. Eventually it was thrown out with the rubbish. A woodcutter/carpenter found it and took it home, he made it into gifts for his children and the Christmas tree was so happy.

This would have been when I was around 7/8, so mid to late 80s.

Comment: So the tree was a conscious being with thoughts/emotions? And it was happy to have been chopped up into pieces? (And still alive after that?)

Comment: Not the [The Crooked Little Christmas Tree by Raymond Fouse](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bM3nc4tFC8g). He doesn't get turned into toys

Comment: @LogicDictates, I heard a similar story when I was a tot.  A bun fell off a baker van,  and lay in the gutter next to a puddle of rainwater. The bun was sad because he had been looking forward to being eaten, while the puddle was sad because he had wanted to be drunk.  Happy ending, along came a mother duck with a lot of little ducklings. They ate the bun and drank the puddle, and they happily said goodbye to each other as they died. Very disturbing.

Comment: It sounds like it's probably something of an allegory (rather than something to take literally).